# Age difference between Bridget and Kerry?

Tags: 8-simple-rules

In "8 Simple Rules", what is the age difference between Bridget and Kerry?

I have watched the complete 3 seasons of the show and got no clue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this site](http://www.tv.com/shows/8-simple-rules/pilot-180030/) and [this site](http://www.tvrage.com/8_Simple_Rules/episodes/312482) Bridget and Kerry are 16 and 15 years old at the beginning of the first season. This seems about right to me as there are a couple of episodes in which they have to take driver's tests and there's a prom in the 3rd season.

Comment: Oddly enough, Amy Davidson (Kerry) is actually *older* than Kaley Cuoco (Bridget) by a whole six years.

Comment: My question is, is there any point in the series which gives out there age difference. What episode/scene is it?